# QDialog::setResult with custom return values

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

*please note: qt/c++ newbie here*

**Purpose:**

I have a QDialog from which I want to return a result. I am aware of the `QDialog::exec()` which combined with setResult, results in the use of `Accept()` or `Reject()`,

but as the [documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#setResult) reads, the developers *suggest* to sue the QDialog return codes, implying that different values *can* be used although I have had no luck with this.

```
enum ReturnResult{
    success=0,
    fail=1
    error=2
    warning=3
}
```

How may I use the `QDialog::setResult()` function to send custom `enum` values to (as seen above),

as a result, back to the parent class, if this is not possible, any suggestion as to how I may solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`QDialog::done(int res)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#done) to close a dialog with the desired result code, which then will be the return value of `QDialog::exec()`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `result()` states that

> In general returns the modal dialog's result code, `Accepted` or `Rejected`.

If I understand correctly, that means that even if the current implementation allows passing custom values, you cannot be certain that it won't change and break your code in the future.

In your case, simply add another signal to it and connect to it, or add your own field to your dialog and use it to pass the data.